# ASP.NET CORE OpenXml altChunk merge many documents into a stream will not merge all documents

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Only one of the  5 documemnts will merge into the stream. This procedure completes without any exceptions and returns the document stream.
The error message from Microsoft Word is "Word found unreadable content. Do you want to recover the contents for this document?" 
I'm new with working with OpenXml...I'm thinking my issue is with the altChunk

```
public IActionResult WordMergeStream()
    {
        //Create a stream and merge 5 word documents into the stream.
        //Use _hostingEnvironment context for Path
        string strWebRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        //Use Memory Stream 
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        //there test five files
        string[] filepaths = new[] { @"/assets/Documents/Document1.docx", @"/assets/Documents/Document2.docx", @"/assets/Documents/Document3.docx", @"/assets/Documents/Document4.docx", @"/assets/Documents/Document5.docx" };
        for (int i = 0; i < filepaths.Length; i++)
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(memoryStream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.WordprocessingDocumentType.Document, true))
            {
                string fn = @filepaths[i];
                MainDocumentPart myMainDocumentPart = myDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Document(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body()).Save(myMainDocumentPart);
                //Create the Document Body and some sample text
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Body body = myMainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
                body.Append(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(
                            new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(
                                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text("...Sample Text..."))));
                //Add the chunk
                string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + i;
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = myMainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(strWebRootPath + @filepaths[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                }
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk altChunk = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.AltChunk() { Id = altChunkId };
                myMainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, myMainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().Last());
                myMainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                myDocument.Close();
        }
    string strFileDownloadName = "my.docx";
    memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return new FileStreamResult(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") { FileDownloadName = strFileDownloadName };
```